# Paypal can't reach my website (IPN, .htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, paypal-ipn

When someone pays with paypal standard in my opencart site, the payment gets done, but the IPN notification never reaches my site. 
The return address is fine, but it seems like paypal is unable to reach my website.

Is there something I could change in my .htaccess file or hosting settings? I really don't know what to do now.

I even created a dummy php script called ipn.php in my site that sends me an email when it's opened. I gave it's address to paypal as the notification address but it doesn't get called neither!

UPDATE: After testing with the IPN simulator in Paypal's sandbox, I am getting the following error: **IPN Delivery Failed:I/O error: Connection timed out; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out**

My htaccess file:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /farmaciagimeno.com/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) /farmaciagimeno.com/index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]


### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

RedirectMatch 301 ^/farmaciagimeno.com(.*)$ http://www.farmaciagimeno.com$1
```

Comment: I don't know, what does your `.htaccess` look like now? Do you receive any errors in your server log? Please share what you have at the moment...

Comment: I don't see any error message in my server log. I updated my question with the .htaccess file

Comment: Seems like you're not the only one having issues with the PayPal IPN. There was another question asked this morning, not the same question but same IPN issues.